# Recover overwritten CSV files with multiple worksheets

Tags: ubuntu, libreoffice, sublime-text, excel

- I have a CSV file with one worksheet.
- After editing with Libre Office, I saved it and opened it with Libre Office again.
- I created a new sheet in the Libre Office.
- I saved it and opened it with Sublime Text.
- I couldn't see the data from both sheets. Still, I edited in Sublime Text and saved the .csv file.
- I reopened the workbook with Libre Office again.
  All my previous worksheets are lost. Only the last worksheet is remaining.

I have been working on the other sheets for almost the past 10 days. All the work seems like it's gone. Ultimate frustration :( Is there a way to restore the lost data?

Comment: If you had checked the "Always create backup copy" option, then it may be possible to find a recent version in the backups directory, as described here [How to recover former version of document](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/6652/how-to-recover-former-version-of-document/). Otherwise it's likely down to forensic tools unfortunately. The CSV format AFAIK doesn't support multiple sheets - likely libreoffice warned you about that ("This document may contain formatting or content that cannot be saved in the currently selected file format “Text CSV”.") and you went ahead anyway?

Comment: I know csv doesn't support multiple sheets, but libre office should at least give me a warning while trying to save the document. This is not expected.

Comment: "Always create backup copy" has been disabled by default. Again, not expected